# Codename One Maven unable to send Android build

Tags: android, build, codenameone

I migrated from Ubuntu to Arch a couple of months ago. On Ubuntu, I built quite e few Android applications using CN1.

Now, on Arch, I am trying to build my first Android app with Maven and Eclipse, and went though the CN1 maven tuts.

After a learning curve, I got the project structured mounted and the simulator up and running, and today I wanted to install the app on my phone, but I received the following error :

```
Buildfile: /home/xxx/eclipse-workspace/xxx/xxxx/build.xml does not exist
```

I searched the entire project and the was really no such file present in any folder. (It should be automatically generated, right?)

Well, I tried to help myself and copied the build.xml file from a project that I generated from the templates to my maven project and created a couple of missing folders (like .../lib/impl/native/javase), but all to no avail.

The last error that's thrown is :

```
BUILD FAILED .../build.xml:434: Can't assign value '${codename1.version}' to attribute version, reason: class java.lang.NumberFormatException with message 'For input string: "${codename1.version}"'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use the plugin to send an Android build and it's looking for the old ant build file which is no longer there.

You need to use the appropriate launch script on Eclipse to send an Android build. The plugin is no longer needed when working with Maven as it's all handled by maven targets now.

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer. I am a little lost : where do I find this script and how do I launch it?

Comment: I imagine the scripts are some folder in the project structure, but wherever folder I click on (test, test-android, test-common, etc.), I get the same error message :   build.xml does not exist

Comment: Did you look under tools/eclipse? Did you read the "Eclipse Users" note in the `README.adoc`?

Comment: @rainer First of all, you need to move some files. As Shai suggested, read the "readme". After that, read this documentation: https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/ There are instructions for command-line, Intellij, Netbeans and Eclipse.

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani, thanks for your input. I got it figured out. The problem was actually not moving any files, since the project runs in the simulator and I had done everything according to the manual and followed the instructions for Eclipse. What I hadn't found was that one needs to choose "Send Android Build" from the dropdown beside the Run button. This step is not in the manual. Would it be a good idea to add it?

Comment: Sure, feel free to submit an edit to the docs

Comment: Will be a pleasure ...  didn't even know that this is possible. Will so so in the coming days. Should I raise an issue on GitHub?